# AwesomeWM nice is not loading

Tags: awesome-wm

I am one version 4.3 of awesomeWM so that should be correct. I have git cloned [nice](https://github.com/mut-ex/awesome-wm-nice) into `~/.config/awesome` and added these lines after beautiful.init(...):

```lua
local nice = require("nice")
nice()
```

Upon reloading i get this error:

```
/user/share/lua/5.3/Gdk.lua:23 bad argument #1 to 'registerlock' (userdata expected, got nil)
```

and

````
Error while running function!
stack traceback:
[C] in function 'lgi.corelgilua51.registerblock'
/usr/share/lua/5.3/lgi/override/Gdk.lua:23 in main chunk
[C] in function 'require'
/usr/share/lua/5.3/lgi/namespace.lua:183: in function 'lgi.init.require'
(...tail calls...)
/home/dev/.config/awesome/nice/init.lua:57: in main chunk
[C] in function 'require'
/home/dev/.config/awesome/rc.lua:50: in main chunk
error: /usr/share/lua/5.3/lgi/override/Gdk.lua:23: bad argument #1 to 'registerlock' (userdata expected, got nil)```
````

Comment: Quick look at their doc. Did you use the branch for v4.3 or the branch for git-master? If git-master, try with the correct branch?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing "`local gdk = lgi.Gdk" to "local gdk = lgi.require('Gdk', '3.0')`" in the init.lua of nice. Also, make sure the branch is pointing to origin/awesome-4v3-stable